# Passing arbitrarily complex bash to `bash -c` - a one liner that doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, shell

My problem is that I want to pass a string containing arbitrarily complex bash to `bash -c "<command>"`, but I've found one case that doesn't behave as expected.

```
bash -c "s=\"hi\"; for _ in 1 2 3; do echo $s; s=\"$s hi\"; done"
```

I'd expect the command to output a little right angled triangle of hi's, like so:

```
hi
hi hi
hi hi hi
```

But instead the command outputs:

Which presumably means `$s` is unset. My suspicion is that it's because of how bash is parsed, in that it's parsed line by line.

How could I make this one line `bash -c` command work? Is this a downside / something to be wary of with this approach of simply passing a potentially quite complex bash script in one line to `bash -c`?

Thanks very much in advance :)
Luke

Comment: `$s` is expanded by the first shell before ever running the second.

Comment: Why do you **want** to do this? Unless this is a programming exercise, or you enjoy suffering from quoting hell, it would be easier to either just write the statements into one line. Why do you want to have a separate bash child process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using another `bash` shell ?

You simply need:

```
s="hi"
for _ in 1 2 3; do
  echo "$s"
  s="$s hi"
done
```

Or using *here-doc* with single quote to prevent shell expansion:

```
bash<<'EOF'
s="hi"
for _ in 1 2 3; do
  echo "$s"
  s="$s hi"
done
EOF
```

Or reusing your command with proper single quotes and no escaping:

```
bash -c 's="hi"; for _ in 1 2 3; do echo $s; s="$s hi"; done'
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

### Output

```
hi
hi hi
hi hi hi
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that the `$` characters aren't escaped, so `$s` is getting expanded (to the empty string) before the command is passed to `bash -c`. You can see this by replacing `bash -c` with `echo`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "s=\"hi\"; for _ in 1 2 3; do echo $s; s=\"$s hi\"; done"
s="hi"; for _ in 1 2 3; do echo ; s=" hi"; done
```

You can see that the `echo $s;` part turned into just `echo ;`, and `s=\"$s hi\"` into `s=" hi"`.

You can either escape the `$` characters, or switch to single-quoting the entire command instead of double-quoting it (and remove the other escapes).

More generally, anytime you have a situation like this where a string/command/whatever is passing through multiple levels of parsing (here, it's first parsed by your interactive shell, then again by the `bash -c` shell), it's critical to understand what's being expanded/applied by each level vs what's passed through to the next level. You often need multiple levels of quoting and/or escaping to control exactly when in the parsing process a particular thing gets acted on (vs just passed through to the next level). Above, I used `printf` to see what had happened after just the first level of parsing, and doing tests like this can help a lot with understanding what's going on. (Note: I prefer `printf '%s\n'` over `echo`, because some versions of `echo` will try to interpret escape sequences themselves, which can add confusion.)

Comment: Thank you! Single quoting the entire line worked :) But, I agree, it's important to understand the parsing that's applied by each shell, and it wasn't really something I understood and thought to think of.